# Auto complete field selected value not getting passed to controller class

Tags: apex, javascript, jquery, salesforce-id, autocomplete

JQuery helps good to select a value from auto complete field but it is not passed to the controller. So, my search result query is not getting modified properly as desired. I can't get where I do any wrong. Can someone please help?

**APEX PAGE:**

```
  <apex:pageblockSectionItem id="selRep"> 
                   <apex:outputText rendered="{!userType == 'Admin' || userType == 'HomeOffice' || userType == 'Field' || userType=='ABS CI Reviewer' || userType=='Sample CI Reviewer'}">Representative Name</apex:outputText>

                   <apex:inputText styleClass="apexRepautocomplete" value="{!selectedRep}"  id="Rep" />  

                </apex:pageblockSectionItem>
```

**Autocomplete function is as below:**

```
 j$(document).ready(function(){

   j$(".apexRepautocomplete").autocomplete({

        source : apexRepList,
       select: function(event, ui){ this.value = ui.item.value;  }  //jsApplyFilter("'" + ui.item.value + "'");
   });     

  });
```

Comment: Can you please post your code where you are passing in the controller.